# Check the progress while training the model using tqdm

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, tqdm

I know how to check the progression of iterations progress using tqdm:

```
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(100)):
time.sleep(0.1)
```

I wanted to check the progress of training of my Random Forest model. Something like:

```
//tqdm_notebook starts the progress bar 
RF_model=RandomForestRegressor(max_features='sqrt',n_estimators=100,oob_score=True)
RF_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
//tqdm_notebook stops the progress bar
```

Comment: It is not tqdm, but you can use the `verbose` parameter to have some information about how things are going when training

Comment: I tried the following code: `RF2=RandomForestRegressor(verbose=True,n_estimators=100)  
 RF2.fit(x_train[:10000],x_test[:10000])` and it does not display a progress bar, just a line at the end, saying `[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:   45.4s finished` . I want something which will continously update me about the training.

Comment: Try `verbose=2`

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter `verbose` for the same.

As per your code, just add one more parameter:

```
RF_model=RandomForestRegressor(max_features='sqrt', n_estimators=100, oob_score=True, verbose=2) 
RF_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Comment: It's not the same by any stretch of the imagination :\